# Added a pause function that wont work. Anyone know a solution?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have added this pause function to my game:

```
function pauseGame() {
    if (!gamePaused) {
        game = clearTimeout(game);
        gamePaused = true;
    } else if (gamePaused) {
        game = setTimeout(drawGame, speed - (level * 50));
        gamePaused = false;
    }
};
```

but for some reason, it wont pause the game. Can anyone figure out why it wont work? The game is [here](http://users.aber.ac.uk/cew10/iwp-project/snake.js).

Comment: Please stop asking the [**same question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218650/how-do-i-pause-my-game) and read the [**faq**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) about what makes a good question.

Comment: how is this a bad question?

Comment: @user2304563 Your question is far too vague for anyone to provide help.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.

Comment: A function without context is very difficult to work with. For example you haven't described any other details about your "game". Even a "demo" of your code would help. What would really help is showing a working example of the problem.

Comment: i did try and attach my source code as a link but it didnt work

Comment: You might want to at least include the code where gamePaused is modified. Also you don't specify how it's not working. Is it not running or not stopping?

Comment: the game runs, when i try to pause the game, it does nothing but if i try to pause it again, the snake speeds up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `game` the first time you call `setTimeout()`. Otherwise when you `clearTimeout(game)`, it throws an error (and doesn't set `gamePaused` to `true`).